# Compiler errors when downloading from Bitbucket

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

For some reason whenever pull code to my work PC via SourceTree and open the project up in unity I am getting errors like this:

> Assets\Scripts\InteractiveMapItem.cs(7,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AppLoader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is occurring with 2 of my scripts, they are not showing as C# files when I pull from the server. There is no ability to right-click open properties of the file like other C# files would allow me to.

I've checked each files "Metadata" and there are no inconsistencies between the server and the local code I have.

This also is only affecting the computer I have in the office (which is new and only has Unity, Visual Studio 2019, and a few select VR related applications needed for development.

Any ideas on a fix?

Here is a picture of the C# files in the "Scripts" folder:

[image]

Comment: Do those files look right when you open them in a simple text editor?

Comment: Yes, I've also opened them with visual studio and even the Intellisense works for the Unity specific and even Class specific files.